# pixels in Graphic mode are deleted while moving the mouse on the printed pixels

Tags: assembly, pixel

I work in graphic mode (320X200).

I wrote a code that print line on the place the mouse crusor is clicked.

Is print the pixels, but when I move the mouse, some pixels disapear.

```
ParX equ [bp+8]
ParY equ [bp+6]
ParColor equ [bp+4]

proc PrintPixel
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    mov bh, 0
    mov cx, ParX
    mov dx, ParY
    mov al, ParColor
    mov ah, 0ch
    int 10h
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop bp
    ret 6
endp PrintPixel

;main

    mov ax,0h
    int 33h
    mov ax,1h
    int 33h

MouseLP:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h ; check left mouse click
    jne MouseLP

    push cx
    push dx
    mov al, [color]
    push ax
    call CreateX
```

Comment: Why do you utlize RET 6 at the end of PrintPixel? Why don't you utilize only RET?  I mean, you may forcing the execution pointer to jump into color/coordinate [BP + 6].

Comment: @DavidBS: That looks fine to me.  `ret 6` pops args off the stack *after* popping the return address.  It's the only efficient way to implement a caller-cleans-the-stack calling convention.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it shoudn't be true ONLY if after the end we hadn't POPed all registers and BP? I can't see it as regular if all POP's are performed (including original BP).

Comment: @DavidBS: Those aren't the args, those are registers that the function is saving/restoring.  [Both forms of `ret`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html) always look for the return address at `[sp]`, so yes of course you have to pop everything you push inside the function.  How would `ret 6` know which registers to pop data into?  It doesn't literally `pop`, it just increases SP without reading anything but the return address from stack memory.  It's not like ARM's multi-reg `ldmia` / `pop` instruction. See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) for more docs and links.

Comment: No hardware cursor yet back in the stone age.  Notorious about int 33h was that if you modify the display in anyway then you have to hide the cursor first and restore it afterwards.  If you don't then pixels will indeed seem to disappear when you hide or move the mouse.  Since that restores the original pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they can disappear, pixels don't do that in 320x200 mode. I'm pretty sure they are there.

What you call "disappear" is maybe you setting them to value you didn't want to, like zero.

To erase the mouse cursor, you should set pixels where cursor WAS with pixel values from the background image, which is supposed to be "under" cursor.

You can do this like (pseudo code):

```
drawCursor:  ; draw cursor at x, y
    ; there should be no cursor at screen before calling this
    mov   [oldMouseX],x
    mov   [oldMouseY],y
    copy_memory(to backgroundBuffer, from vram at x,y, cursor size x/y)
    blit_cursor(at x, y, cursor gfx)
    ret

hideCursor: ; before drawing it at new position
    blit_memory(at [oldMouseX], [oldMouseY], from backgroundBuffer, cursor size x/y)
    ret
```

About those copy/blit...
It's common to create some "sprite" manipulation routines, like for example:

```
blit_transparent_gfx:
  ; params x, y, gfx data ptr, gfx data sizex, gfx data sizey
  ; globals word [ScreenSizeX] = 320, byte [transparent color]

  ; calculate direct address into VRAM into es:di
    push 0a000h
    pop  es      ; es pointing to VRAM
    mov  ax,[ScreenSizeX] ; 320
    mul  word [param y]
    add  ax,[param x]
    mov  di,ax   ; es:di = VRAM address to write pixels
  ; prepare registers for outside line loop
    mov  ah,[transparent color]
    mov  si,[param gfx data ptr]
    mov  dx,[param gfx data sizey]
blit_transparent_line:
  ; outer line loop
    mov  cx,[param gfx data sizex]
    push di
  ; inner loop drawing pixels
blit_transparent_pixel:
    mov  al,[si]
    cmp  al,ah
    jz   blit_transparent_pixel_skip
    mov  [es:di],al
blit_transparent_pixel_skip:
    inc  si
    inc  di
    dec  cx
    jnz  blit_transparent_pixel
  ; move VRAM pointer one line down
    pop  di
    add  di,[ScreenSizeX]
    dec  dx
    jnz  blit_transparent_line
    ret
```

Routines to store/recover background image can be a bit simpler, as they don't have to test for transparency, but the principle is same (copy memory from/to VRAM of size [sizex, sizey] to some internal buffer, or from gfx data).

Don't use `int 10h` for pixel drawing, drawing directly to `A000:xxxx` VRAM is very simple in 320x200 mode (you should have seen VRAM organization on ZX Spectrum, or even better one, Atari 2600 console (hint: it has no VRAM at all), now those were not trivial, but 13h mode on VGA is pure joy to use directly). Very simple, and much much much faster, even this naive unoptimized "blit_transparent_gfx" (written so, that it should be easy to understand how it works) will be blazingly fast when compared to anything involving `int 10h` call.

PS. I didn't debug that "blit_transparent_gfx" (obviously you have firstly to fix those pseudo `[param ...]` lines with real code anyway, just to compile it), so maybe I did some bug there, feel free to debug it then (although I'm sort of sure it should work as is, once you fix the syntax).